Odoo: Updating on hand quantity in stock.quant
I created a server action where when the user clicks it, it will decrement the user's onhand quantity but it won't force save
for record in records:
    location = record.x_studio_stock_location
    quant = env['stock.quant'].search([('location_id', '=', record.x_studio_tools.id)], limit=1)

    if quant and quant.location_id == location:

        new_inventory_quantity = quant.quantity- 1

        quant.sudo().write({'quantity': new_inventory_quantity})

Is there like a automated pre-coded action of odoo that prevents this code? Like do I have to go through a process in Inventory Adjustment to be able to adjust the quantity of a product?

What about using stock.quant._update_available_quantity() instead of a single write? Why do you search for quants with location a but compare it with location b instead of searching immediately with location b?

I did some research and with the help of @CZoellner. This is how I've updated the onhand quantity in model stock.quant
env['stock.quant']._update_available_quantity(record.x_studio_tools,record.x_studio_stock_location,1).

Thank you @CZoellner
